# Integration of non cartesian basis vectors without transforming them back to cartesian

Tags: integration, tensors

Doing some E&M problems I stumbled upon this volumetric flux integral

$$ \\\iiint_V \frac{(2cos(\theta)\ \hat{e_r} + sin(\theta)\ \hat{e_{\theta}})}{r^3} dV$$

Now, I know the standard way of solving this integrals is transforming the polar basis vectors into cartesian and solving normally, but I'm also studying some tensor calculus on the side and wondered if there is some "covariant integration" process which  I may not be aware of.

Keep in mind, my main focus is not just solving the integral, is learning how to specifically solve it using the basis vectors given (or learning if it's even possible). Thanks in advance!